# Converting collections performance

Tags: performance, scala, collections, immutability

In my code I working with different types of collections and often converting one to another. I do it easily calling `toList`, `toVector`, `toSet`, `toArray` functions.

Now I am interested in performance of this operations. I find information about `length`, `head`, `tail`, `apply` performance in [documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html).  What actually happens when I call functions(`toList`, `toVector`, `toSet`, `toArray`) on `List`, `Set`, `Array` and `Vector` implementation in scala?

P.S. Question is only about standard scala collections which is immutable.

Comment: If you are happy to read scala source code: https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection

Comment: @Pavel I try to read it by I can't understand it, one good explanation will be nice, don't you think so? Every one can google this question, and get the basic idea, isn't it great?

Comment: If you don't understand any specific segment of code, you are free to update you answer with more details. There is enough people here who will be happy to help. Please be more specific. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well my advice would be: look yourself into the source code ! For instance, method toSet is defined as follow in the TraversableOnce trait (annotated by myself) :

```
  def to[Col[_]](implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, A, Col[A @uV]]): Col[A @uV] = {
    val b = cbf() //generic way to build the collection, if it would be a List, it would create an empty List
    b ++= seq // add all the elements
    b.result() //transform the result to the target collection
  }
```

So it means that the toSet method has a performance of O(N) since you traverse all the list once! I believe that all the collections inheriting this trait are using this implementation.

Comment: Not exactly... If an insertion into a set would take constant time, you would be correct. So to be complete: it would take `O(n * <time taken to insert 1 element>)`. So in case a `Set` is implemented using a BST the `toSet` function would be `O(n log(n))`.